# How can I run a task every morning, even if the phone restarted before in Xamarin (pref. Android and IOS) using for example Shiny?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, shiny, automation

I have 2 interfaces:

- Agenda: an interface to get the ICal of my day.
- Spotify: an interface for the Spotify API in C#.

I want a task to run in the morning, which checks my first appointment of the day. It then should schedule a task to run like 1.5 hours before the appointment. This task will call Spotify functions, which are like an alarm.

Does someone know how this could be achieved for at least Android?

Thank you for your response in advance!

I tried to use BroadcastReceiver with Booting to continuously run a task, but I don't think that this could be a valid solution.

I tried to look into Shiny, but I still don't understand the Android principals of backgrounding and clock systems

Answer (score 0):

What you need is probably background services

Android: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/services/foreground-services

IOS: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/backgrounding/ios-backgrounding-techniques/

As for the steps in android:

1. Activate android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE in the android manifest
2. Create an Intent Service that performs your spotify actions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/services/creating-a-service/intent-services
3. With the android context you can wherever you want run StartForeGroundService(yourIntent)

You can also wrap your actions in a notification like in this example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/services/foreground-services

In the next days i will create an sample and post the link in there but i hope it helps you out for now.

Comment: This looks like it has potential. I will try this soon.
Thanks for your submission!